# Restful API. Cannot add data from Android app to MySQL database using Laravel

Tags: php, android, laravel, rx-java

I am trying to add data from android app to mysql database using
*RxJava* and *Laravel* for *RestFul API*. I was not able to add data to the database, I think my php code is not correct. Below is my some code for POST method.

**StudentController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Student;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class StudentController extends Controller
{       
    function addData(Request $req) {
        $st = new Student;
        $st->name = $req->name;
        $st->age = $req->age;
        if ($st->save()) {
            echo "Add 1 field success !";
        } 
    } 
}
```

**JsonApi.kt**

```
package com.example.demo9

import io.reactivex.Observable
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.*

interface JsonApi {
    
    // For laravel

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("add2")
    fun insertStudent(@Field("name") name: String, @Field("age") age: Int):
            Observable<Response<Void>>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

The problem has been solved by me.
By adding the url declaration to the app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    
    protected $except = [
        'api/add2/*'
    ];
}
```